# Permanent PATH variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, .profile, mongodb

How will I make this `/media/De Soft/mongodb/bin` PATH variable permanent?

Everyone is saying "`export PATH=$PATH:media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin` to your `~/.profile`, or `.bashrc`, or `.zshenv` depending on your shell".

I don't know what is `~/.profile`, or `.bashrc`, or `.zshenv`. What do they do actually?

How will I add `export PATH=$PATH:my/path` to my .profile/.bashrc/.zshenv?

I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with default terminal.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

They are configuration files. One way:

- Open a terminal window using **Ctrl+Alt+T**
- Run the command `gedit ~/.profile`
- Add the line

  `export PATH=$PATH:/media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin`

  to the bottom and save
- Log out and log in again

*Edit:*

A safer way is to use quotes. Doing so is necessary if one or more directories in the original `PATH` contain spaces. So:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/media/De Soft/mongodb/bin"
```

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, do I really need to export PATH var? Maybe, it is done by default in some other script? I have checked by ~/.profile and a PATH var is there, but it is not explicitly exported: PATH=~/.local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: @yuranos87: No, you are right; when modifying `PATH` in `~/.profile`, exporting is redundant, since `PATH` already is an environment variable.

Comment: You don't need to logout and login again. Use `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: @timbo: That does not make the variable available to already started processes in the session (except for the current terminal).

Comment: Don't you need a quote mark in the string as in `export PATH="$PATH:/media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin"`? Is it optional?

Comment: @BrunoBentzen: Good question. I edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 15):

To permanently change `PATH` you need to make changes to `/etc/environment` file. Make a backup before editing:

```
sudo cp /etc/environment /etc/environment.bak
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

sample output:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Paths are delimited by `:` so to add a new path say `x/y/z` this will how our `/etc/environment` looks like:

```
PATH="x/y/z:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: Hi, i did what you wrote here and $ echo $PATH reveals: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin   but: sudo nano /etc/environment reveals alot more. like games, i edited the path file, it shows up in NANO, but not in terminal using $echo $PATH, am i alrite?

Comment: @NaturalDemon: It doesn't matter how you did that as long as `PATH` variable contains it correctly you are OK.

Answer (score 6):

Type the following in a terminal window

```
export PATH=/media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin:$PATH
```

Close the terminal and restart  the computer. The path should include /media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin when you type this in the terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: That only works for current terminal session. It needs to be in `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc` on common GNU/Linux distros... even `~/.bash_profile`) to be run on every console load.

Comment: agreed. but upon system restart it is loaded in the path variable.

Comment: @NiveditaVelagaleti: No it's not unless you make it persistent via a config file. The terminal command does not modify `PATH` persistently.

Comment: To be clear, I should *not* put this in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` if I want he variable (`PATH`) to be available to most applications, correct? The [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) says,  
  
"Shell config files such as `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_login`... may work on Bash shells for programs started from the shell, [but] variables set in those files are not available by default to programs started from the graphical environment in a desktop session."

Answer (score 0):

You could also just write directly to the `~/.profile` from terminal:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/media/De\ Soft/mongodb/bin' >> ~/.profile
```