# How to make added PATH permanent

Tags: command-line, 16.04, paths

I recently installed Swift 3.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04, and if I want to access the swift shell, I have to put in

```
    export PATH=/home/thebigfootsdad/Downloads/swift-3.0-preview-1-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

every time I open terminal.
Is there any way to make this permanent?


I am not really familiar with command-line, and I would appreciate more simple answers please!

I have gone through most of the threads here on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanent PATH variable](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500775/permanent-path-variable) (or http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path and a bunch of others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the new `PATH` to your `~/.bashrc` by:

```
echo 'export PATH=/home/thebigfootsdad/Downloads/swift-3.0-preview-1-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin:"${PATH}"' >>~/.bashrc
```

Or use your favorite editor to edit `~/.bashrc` and add the following at the end:

```
export PATH=/home/thebigfootsdad/Downloads/swift-3.0-preview-1-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```