# Export PATH does not work after restart

Tags: command-line, paths

I am new to this. I installed drush and did

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush
```

So that I can execute drush from the command line with the drush command
My issue is that I have to execute this command at every restart for it to work. How can I make this permanent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanent PATH variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500775/permanent-path-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add your command to your **~/.bashrc** file
ex:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush" >> ~/.bashrc
```

then reload the file

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!