# How can I add a directory to my path and add a command to .bashrc? I am working with Supernova-2.1.1 of 10X Genomics

Tags: command-line, server, bashrc

I would like to add a directory to my path, in my IBM server running Ubuntu 22.04. I would like to install the genome assembly software, SuperNova-2.1.1 by 10x genomics. In order to start using their `supernova` command, I must add the directory to my path. The path was added using the following command:

```
export PATH=/opt/supernova-2.1.1:$PATH
```

They have also suggested adding the path to `.bashrc`, which I don't know how to perform. Anyways, the problem is when I try to invoke their `supernova` command, the prompt says `command 'supernova' not found`. Can someone help me understand the problem, and how to add the command to the `.bashrc`?

NB: The details on how to navigate through the installation can be found [here](https://support.10xgenomics.com/de-novo-assembly/software/pipelines/latest/installation).

Comment: *"adding the path to .bashrc, which I don't know how to perform"* you just open the file in any text editor, and type your changes - see for example [Permanent PATH variable](https://askubuntu.com/a/500794/178692)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Does it work if you run `/opt/supernova-2.1.1/supernova`?  If not, then it isn't installed properly, and adding it to the path isn't going to help.

Comment: Also a question - You have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but you mention that you are running Ubuntu on your "IBM server".  This doesn't quite match up.  WSL is a Microsoft feature for running Ubuntu under *Windows*, not on an IBM server.  It probably doesn't matter for this question, but you may want to clarify or remove the WSL tag.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the problem was resolved by invoking the supernova command as follows: ./supernova